# How can I slice a list based on the lengths from another list?

Tags: python, list

I got two lists:

```
list1 = [4,6,4] 

list2 = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

Now I want to create a new list, which contains the first four items(because of list1[0] = 4) from `list2` as one listelement.

```
list3 = [(1,1,1,1),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `slice` the list based on the values from the list, like this

```
list1 = [4, 6, 4]
list2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

# Create an iterator for the list
it = iter(list2)

from itertools import islice
print([tuple(islice(it, item)) for item in list1])
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: i got this error: ValueError: Stop argument for islice() must be None or an integer: 0 <= x <= sys.maxsize.

Comment: @Nekoso Are you using some other data apart from what you have shown in the question? In that case, please make sure that all the items in `list1` are valid numbers. BTW, please take a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/zeE6L8)

Comment: ive read the datatype and every number in list1 has a string declaration.Is that the problem?

Comment: @Nekoso Yes, you need to convert them to numbers then. Try this `[tuple(islice(it, int(item))) for item in list1]`

Comment: i got another little question, when i try to write it in a txt. this error is coming:

Comment: i got another little question, when i try to write it in a txt. this error is coming:Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly. I have to change the tuple datatype to a string?

Comment: @Nekoso If you want to store the structure as it is, then yes. You need to convert it to String. But I would recommend a standard format like JSON.